# Dropdown list value update into the another gridview column value while select index changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

The HTML code for my `GridView` is:

```asp
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
    CellSpacing="4" ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" BackColor="White" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                ItemvId</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemId" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item_Id") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Item Name</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item_Name") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Item Price</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemPrice" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item_Price") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Item Description</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item_Description") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Quantity</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuantity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="ddlQuantity_TextChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1" Selected="True" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3" />
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Total</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="" EnableViewState="True"></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnapprove" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
                    CommandName="Add" runat="server" Text="Add" BackColor="#5E610B" ForeColor="White" /></ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#61380B" Font-Size="Large" Font-Names="Rockwell" ForeColor="White">
    </HeaderStyle>
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#61380B"></PagerStyle>
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" Font-Size="18px" Font-Names="Rockwell" ForeColor="#61380B"
        HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Height="20px" BorderColor="Black"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"></RowStyle>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#DF0101" ForeColor="#61380B"></SelectedRowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

and the code behind that is:

```
protected void ddlQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtGetRestaurent = new DataTable();
    RestaurantRequestBAL objgetallcountry = new RestaurantRequestBAL();
    objProp.ItemTypes = lblmsg.Text.ToString().Trim();
    dtGetRestaurent = objgetallcountry.GetDatalistFromItemTypes(objProp);
    GridView1.DataSource = dtGetRestaurent;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    DropDownList ddlLabTest = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row1 = (GridViewRow)ddlLabTest.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList chkQuantiity = (DropDownList)row1.FindControl("ddlQuantity");
    Label totalOrderItem = (Label)row1.FindControl("lblTotal");
    Label getprice = (Label)row1.FindControl("lblItemPrice");
    int Quant = int.Parse(chkQuantiity.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
    int Price = int.Parse(getprice.Text);
    int total = Quant * Price;
    totalOrderItem.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

How can I update that row’s `lbltotal` based on the dropdown list?

Comment: What is issue in this code? what error you are getting.

Comment: How does this not work/

Comment: actually that row's lblTotal is not updating. ..  . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done with javascript and ajax. You should refresh your data after value in dropdown list is changed. I think that approach with gridview controll will be pain in the ass for this kind of things. Take a look on knockout js, bootstrap ui, and make your own grid easily.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?